# Swift Class Variable as Method Parameter

Tags: class, swift, ios8, xcode6

I have a Swift Class called Person and it has three values: First name, last name and birthday (`String`, `String` and `NSDate`). Now I have function which I want to use to print something based on an attribute - for example when the attribute is `myPerson.name` it should print the following: `This person's name is ...`. My question is now is it possible to make a function which takes a parameter of the class Person as parameter? For example: `func myFunction(parameter:Person.parameter) {}` (I know there's no Person.parameter but it's just an example).
I know there are easier solutions but it would be helpful for me for another project. Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new property  name and override it's getter to return 'This person's name is  ... ' text,

```
class Person{
    let firstName: String
    let lastName: String

    init(firstName: String, lastName: String) {
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
    }

    var name: String {
        get {
           return "This person's name is \(firstName) \(lastName)"
        }
    }
}


let person = Person(firstName: "Sandeep", lastName: "Koirala")
person.name
```

Regarding the function, you can create a new function which takes Person as object and then perform some calculation on its property like this,

```
func printPersonsName(person: Person) {
    print(person.name)
}
```

Comment: Yeah I'm aware of that but I have a larger project where I have about 25 properties and need almost the same lines of code (about 20 lines) to get a value for each of them and I don't want to copy 20 lines code 25 times .. I would rather do a switch case function based on a number which "equals" a parameter and then get the value using another function which takes a class' property as parameter

Comment: So, why dont you extract those into some methods or some class, that would help you to keep your code dry.

Comment: That's what I want to do but I don't know how to do that better

Comment: Well, it happens every now and then, you just have to try to see those repetitions and then try to extract it into some methods.

Comment: Is it possible to store all properties of a class in an array? It's not, is it?

Comment: Why not it is possible.

Comment: Would be great if you had an example for me ;) so that I have an array with array[0] = myPerson.firstName and so on